# Differnt types when passed to same generic type parameter does not throw error

Tags: java

In the below code why JAVA does not throw any error. When does the compiler know whether the type passed is Integer or String.

Why this is not ambiguous for the compiler?

```
public static <T> T foo(T x, T y) {
        return x ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer a = 0;
        String b = "bar";
        System.out.println(foo(a, b)); 
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: have you considered the possibility that both Integer and String are instances of Object, and thus that type is being used?

Comment: Basically Java tries to determine the correct type for <T>.  Without constraints, <T> can always be an `Object`, so basically any type can be passed in.

Comment: Got it.. thanks @Stultuske.. It was easy. I should have figured it out before. Thanks!